# Why can't I close this question as a dupe?

Tags: bug

This question

[Short story about alien military telepathy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28044/short-story-about-alien-military-telepathy/49907#49907)

is a dupe of this question...

[Which 70s/80s story/book has horses as protagonists?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66305/which-70s-80s-story-book-has-horses-as-protagonists/66307#66307)

but when I try to close it as a dupe (with my gold-tag privilege), I get this warning

[image]

I was able to close [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7569/short-story-about-a-highly-intelligent-species-without-any-technology/7570#7570) as a dupe of the first question a few seconds earlier.

Comment: I think the bigger question is, why were you trying to close it as a duplicate when it has no accepted answer? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That's my bad. Regardless of the fact that it stopped me doing something foolish. I'd still like to know why it wouldn't close this question.

Comment: I voted to close the same question as a duplicate (and retracted my close vote afterward, of course). I had no issue doing so, but I do not have a gold badge in [tag:story-identification].

Comment: It’s possible that this is a bug related to the code that prevents users from closing questions with *open* bounties.

Comment: @Adamant - Hmm. I did bounty it.

Comment: "No disintegrations. Or VTCs" - Darth Vader