# Can't close question as dupe. Just get error message

Tags: bug, closing-questions, duplicate-questions, review-queue

In what looks like another example of the same bug  ([Why can't I close this question as a dupe?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10292/why-cant-i-close-this-question-as-a-dupe)) I don't seem to be able to close [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/young-adult-novel-involving-time-travel-via-a-round-rainbow-like-portal) as a duplicate.

- [Young adult novel involving Time-travel, via a round, rainbow like portal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4304/young-adult-novel-involving-time-travel-via-a-round-rainbow-like-portal)

**Why?**

[image]

---

Update. I can't close it from the review queue either

[image]

Comment: I just successfully voted to close it. Must be something temporary on your end.

Comment: I don't know what's causing the bug, but I find it bizarre that a six year old question gets asked again, someone answers it with slightly more detail.. so the six year old, long since answered question gets closed as a dup.  I understand keeping the one with better data, but this is a bit ridiculous. It would seem to encourage posting duplicate questions to supplant older ones instead of simply providing better answers.  Perhaps some way to merge them might be developed...

Comment: @K-H-W - It's a well-established principle that we close dupes based on quality, not age. The other question and the other answer are both more detailed, hence yours is a dupe of theirs.

Comment: On a possibly useful note, tho -- Gallifreyan just edited out my edit, so could it have been an edit lock?  Might be worth trying again now to see what happens. (I disagree with the policy, but until I can argue for a change I'm not trying to stop you from enforcing it :) )

Comment: @Valorum - I've seen that in another meta posting, but I would suggest that's a bad idea, as it encourages replication of questions, rather than expansion of answers.  That said, that's just my opinion -- but you can probably see how closing a six year old question as a duplicate of a brand new one is a bit.. offputting, if not ludicrous.  Perhaps a different close reason would make sense; 'duplicate' just seems silly in this application.

Comment: @K-H-W - The goal is to make the answer useful to those who find it. Making theirs a dupe of yours means that casual viewers can only see the little stub answer that rintaun wrote. That doesn't include any details about *why* he thinks that's the answer...

Comment: @Valorum - I agree; I would just suggest that when a duplicate is found it would make more sense to import the answers to the original; merge them together or something.  I don't know if there is a technical way to do it, it is just very off-putting and counter intuitive to have a long since answered question closed as a 'duplicate' of a new one.  That said, I have no solution, which is why I'm grumping here instead of proposing a change -- I think one is needed for clarity, but don't know what form it would take.

Comment: :)  At minimum, change the close description: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." - Perhaps "This question has been been asked in an alternate form which contains superior information and/or a superior answer." or some such.

Comment: @K-H-W I seem to remember a relevant main meta feature request, though I can't find it now. FYI, our duplicate policy is the same as on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/348200).

Comment: @Gallifreyan- Thanks; I hope you can find it.  I recognize, too, that it's the same as on Main Meta, and I think it's silly there, too :) -- To me, it's like transferring the copyright on a song to a cover artist who did a 'better' version than the original.  I understand the reasoning (ease of finding good answers).. I just don't like it and think there should be a better solution.

Comment: I don't know why the system wouldn't let you, but, after extended chatting about it, I tossed in the final 'Close: Dup' vote, and it has closed now. (I don't agree with the policy, but since **it is the policy**, I'm doing what I can to support it, while I argue for change.)  Anyway, I hope that it being able to close from that path tells you something diagnostically. (Initially posted this as an answer, and then realized it doesn't really answer your question, so deleted it and moved it here.)

Comment: I can't even see the question now. It comes up with an [error page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/4304/young-adult-novel-involving-time-travel-via-a-round-rainbow-like-portal)

Comment: Wow.  That's... bizarre.  Sounds to me like it's trying to resume an action you started (like respawning the Close Dialog) or something, and erroring out...  Might be worth logging off and seeing if you can see it as a guest.

Comment: @K-H-W - I can't see it on mobile either

Comment: Have you tried logging out?  That might help identify if it's tied to your ID somehow...

Comment: @K-H-W - I just tried it. And closing chrome. No dice. Still getting the error page

Comment: @K-H-W it's worth noting that this is ONLY the case for duplicates. Not other questions. Since Story-IDs can be sure to be a dupe until the answer is accepted

Comment: Nope. Tried logging in on Internet Explorer (yuk) and it's still blocked.

Comment: @Valorum - Hmm. Were you logged into the site on IE?

Comment: @K-H-W - Yes. It's visible if I just guest in, so it must be linked to my profile somehow. Hmm. Should I raise it as a separate bug?

Comment: Ahh.  That suggests it's something pending from your ID that it's trying to bring back to you and failing.. Ugh.  That will probably require some admin work to fix.. Well, at least if it's just this question, it's not too harmful for you.

Comment: @Valorum - I would; I think they are related, but I think you have a process hanging (pardon the term; I'm sure that's not accurate for the web, but I'm an old school geek) that is stopping things.  It's probably the cause of the other problem, too, but I'd still raise a bug as it's likely to get a different kind of attention.

Comment: Did you try to close it as something else? I.e. is it only *dupe* voting that failed, or any kind of close-voting? If the former, might be a dupehammer-specific error.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Just as a dupe. The fact that it's showing as an error page for me alone seems very odd indeed.